# Extracting text with imacros

Tags: imacros

**SITUATION:** I am finding it difficult to EXTRACT a specific text from a website.

The template example on the iMacros website (http://wiki.imacros.net/Data_Extraction#Data_Extraction_and_Web_Scraping) for 
extracting a variable from iMacros is as follows:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:bdytxt&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM
```

However in the html code below, the specific element `<a href="..." target="_blank">text1</a>` doesn't have a class to specify in the `ATTR` section. I am specifically trying to extract **text1** from the example below:

```
//This code is within an html page
<div class="class1">
  <img class="class2" src="...">
  <strong>
    <a href="..." target="_blank">text1</a>
  </strong>
  <br>
  <small>text2</small>
  <small class="class3">
    <br>
    <em>text3:</em>
    <span>
      <a href="..." class="class4">
        <small style="color: #aaa; font-size: 80%">text4</small>
        text5
      </a>
    </span>
    <br>
    <em>text6</em>
    <a href="..." class="class5">text7</a>,
    <a href="..." class="class5">text8</a>
  </small>
</div>
```

**What I have tried:**

I know that when I record using "Experimental event recording mode" and click on the specific **text1** that I get the following code:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(5)>DIV>STRONG>A" BUTTON=0
```

I tested to see if the SELECTOR would work in the EXTRACT code like so:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(5)>DIV>STRONG>A" EXTRACT=TXT
```

but as you can imagine, it didn't.

**QUESTION:** Does anyone know how I can extract **text1** from the above situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there can be several ways to extract this text. For example:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=CLASS:"class2"
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=A ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
```

Or if you use 'iMacros for Chrome', here's a solution with the help of selector:

```
TAG SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(5)>DIV>STRONG>A" EXTRACT=TXT
```

Comment: by the way, I actually have another doubt with imacros that I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636311/imacros-find-how-much-a-scrollbar-is-scrolled if you happen to know the solution you would be my saviour a second time

Comment: I just want to add that you have to disable the multiprocess feature in Firefox when using 'iMacros' v.8.9.7.