# imacros find how much a scrollbar is scrolled

Tags: imacros

**SITUATION:** I am trying to make an imacro that will measure how much a scrollbar is scrolled on a specific page, though I have had various difficulties:

The following javascript code is often used for this purpose:

```
var vertical = document.getElementById("myDIV").scrollTop;
alert("amount scrolled vertically: " + vertical);
```

**ATTEMPT#1:**

However, when I tried using that code in the **firefox imacros extension** in a **js** file, I get the following error:

> *ReferenceError: document is not defined, line 1 (Error code: -991)*

code that produces the error:

```
var info = document.getElementById("myDIV").scrollTop;
alert("info");
```

**ATTEMPT#2:**

So what I tried next was the following code:

```
var info = window.content.document.getElementById("myDIV").scrollTop;
alert("info");
```

but that gives the following error:

> *Error: Accessing content window is not supported in multiprocess Firefox, line 208 (Error code: -991)*

**QUESTION:** Is there a way for me to measure the amount scrolled in the **firefox imacros extension**? And if so, how? I have sadly been stuck on this for the past few days.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Use imacros 8.9.7 version. You can find it here.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/versions/